# Cannot get jsPDF to build and output a PDF document using a custom HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I need your help,

If I refer to the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzz7n/1/) example: it function creates a nice PDF with a table in it that is already "prebuilt".

However, if I were to introduce a custom HTML string into the equation, the function goes stale mate and does nothing, no errors, no nothing. Why is this? The idea/concept does not seem farfetched to me? Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzZ7n/2799/) that I refer.

Here is the function in question:

```
function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
    // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.

    source = '<html><head></head><body><p>this is fun!</p></body></html>'

    // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
    // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
    // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
    // (class, of compound) at this time.
    specialElementHandlers = {
        // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 522
    };
    // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
    // 'inches' in this case
    pdf.fromHTML(
    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function (dispose) {
        // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
        //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
    }, margins);
}
```

Comment: it printed 'this is fun' in the PDF for me alright. Seems like it's working? Did I miss something?

Comment: Your second jsfiddle seems to be working as expected, what is your desired output?

Comment: Wow! Im using IE10, what browser is it working for you then?